# Angular: controller-directive interaction with separation of concerns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, separation-of-concerns

I have an AngularJS module that defines a nice directive that can show a WebGL scene from the `scr="filename"` attribute. That works well and (snipped here and there) looks roughly like this:

```
angular.module('ThreeViewer', [])
.directive('three', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.renderer = new SceneRenderer(element[0])
      $http.get(attr.src)
      .success(function (json) {
        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader()
        var scene = loader.parse(json)
        this.scene = scene
        this.renderer.setScene(scene)
      }.bind(scope))
    },
    restrict: 'AC',
    scope: {
      src: '='
    }
  }
}])
```

So what it does is load the scene, save it to the scope, and pass it to the renderer. This works.

Now I want to create a controller so the user can interact with the data, say to rotate the object. My question is how should one approach this, while adhering to the Angular paradigm of separation of concerns? It is my understanding that in Angular the controller should be able to work without the directive and vice versa -- without knowing anything about each other. Does that mean that the controller cannot directly modify the `scope.scene` object? Then how does one go about it?

Just as a guess, should the controller just "rotate" without knowing what it is rotating? And then how should the directive pick this up?

Or alternatively, is it perfectly fine for the controller to edit `scope.scene`? Then my question is how do I break it out of isolation?

Comment: You have set up an isolated scope with src, so why are you using attrs.src, and not scope.src? And as you have set up an isolated scope, the controller won't be able to update scope.scene as it doesn't have access to it.

Comment: To extend @AbhishekJain comment, here is the documentation for isolate scope https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive. From here, you link the 2 together in the view, via the attributes

Comment: That was not intentional other than that I thought I have to use '=' so I can have two ng-three objects within one controller. Perhaps I misunderstood the tutorial.

Comment: On second thought, if the controller does rotation, then it probably makes no sense to have multiple ng-three objects. Thanks! I don't understand the & and @ values yet, but will look into that in the guide.

Comment: I would add the template and the controller to the directive. If you do that, then your directive becomes an independent module by itself and you shouldn't have to concern about anything else, apart from the shared scope between the directive and the rest of you app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the scene-logic (including the loading/parsing) into an own `service` (or multiple, one for the json-parsing and one for rotating etc). I see no problem with a `conroller` passing the `scene` object to a `service`, it should just not contain specific logic for it, as its role should just be to mediate between `service`s containing logic and the `view`.

For scoping, I would instantiate a `SceneController`(e.g.) for the directive with the `controller` and `controllerAs` parameters and attach the scene to that `controller`. This way the `SceneController` is a specific `controller` to provide a rich view and controls for a `scene`.